# Unity Solution in Visual Studio Subprojects Need Migration

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, migration, project

Self asking to provide answer as I could not find for myself after looking around here and elsewhere.

I doubled clicked a `.cs` file in Unity to open the corresponding VS solution. After VS opened, all the subprojects under the solution had a specific icon and when hovered over said "This project needs to be migrated." and no project items are shown.

[image]

I tried to hard reset my unity project with git (no luck).

Answer (score 0):

After updating Visual Studios (Help > Check for updates) my problem was completely resolved. Cheers.